# Test focus state with Jasmine

Tags: jquery, testing, css-selectors, jasmine, pseudo-class

I guess my question has two parts:

1) How can I test that an element received focus state?

2) In console after running `$(my_input).focus()`, I run `$(my_input).is(':focus')` and get `false`. And yet, `document.activeElement` returns my input. Why is that?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Try checking `document.activeElement` with a delay, inside a `setTimeout`. Also, are you using jsdom, PhantomJS, or something else to simulate the DOM?